# Consuming JSON REST API using Active Resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest

I'm new to rails and am in the process of building my first app. The app in question needs to be built on top of an internally built API which is responsible for interfacing with our data layer.

Having read around on Stack Overflow and the web in general it seems as though Active Resource is a pretty neat tool for this however my question is whether it will work for the specific API I am consuming which is:

1. JSON output
2. Built in PHP and not Rails (although it is RESTful)

(point number 2 is the one I am most concerned about as, from what I have heard/read so far, Active Resource is primarily designed to consume API's from other Rails apps)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. *JSON output* - it will work. Default format is XML, but ActiveResource also supports JSON (PS: you will have to set format to :json somewhere in config).
2. *API is built in PHP* - as long as the response is in standardized format so ActiveResource can parse it, it doesn't really care whether the response was generated by Rails, PHP or monkey behind the typewriter :).

As you said, ActiveResource is used primarily as a way for several Rails applications to interact with each other, but it is also meant to be used in the way you intend to.

Comment: great, thanks for the answer. (also I now plan to get a monkey and a typewriter to help with building out the app down the line, now that I know its possible... :) )